# Sparql query running forever

Tags: java, sparql, jena, tdb

I'm struggling with the execution of a SPARQL query in Jena, with a resulting behaviour that I don't understand...

I'm trying to query the Esco ontology (https://ec.europa.eu/esco/download), and I'm using TDB to load the ontology and create the model (sorry if the terms I use are not accurate, I'm not very experienced).

My goal is to find a job position uri in the ontology that matches with the text I have previously extracted: ex: extracted term : "*acuponcteur*" -> label in ontology: *"Acuponcteur"@fr* -> uri: *<http://ec.europa.eu/esco/occupation/14918>*

What I call the "weird behaviour" is related to the results I'm getting (or not) when excuting queries, ie.:

When executing the following query :

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> 
PREFIX esco: <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/model#>      
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>   
SELECT ?position    
WHERE {     
    ?s rdf:type esco:Occupation. 
    { ?position skos:prefLabel ?label. } 
    UNION 
    { ?position skos:altLabel ?label. } 
    FILTER (lcase(?label)= \"acuponcteur\"@fr ) 
}
LIMIT 10
```

I get those results after 1 minute :

```
-----------------------------------------------
| position                                    |
===============================================
| <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/occupation/14918> |
| <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/occupation/14918> |
| <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/occupation/14918> |
| <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/occupation/14918> |
| <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/occupation/14918> |
| <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/occupation/14918> |
| <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/occupation/14918> |
| <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/occupation/14918> |
| <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/occupation/14918> |
| <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/occupation/14918> |
-----------------------------------------------
```

However, when I'm trying to add the DISTINCT keyword, thus :

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> 
PREFIX esco: <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/model#>      
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>   
SELECT DISTINCT ?position   
WHERE {     
    ?s rdf:type esco:Occupation. 
    { ?position skos:prefLabel ?label. } 
    UNION 
    { ?position skos:altLabel ?label. } 
    FILTER (lcase(?label)= \"acuponcteur\"@fr ) 
}
LIMIT 10
```

it seems like the query keeps running forever (i stopped the execution after 20 minutes waiting...)

I get the same behaviour when executing the same query as the first one (thus without DISTINCT), with another label to match, a label that I'm sure is not in the ontology. While expecting empty result, it (seems like it) keeps running and i have to kill it after a while (once again, i waited 20 minutes to the most) :

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> 
PREFIX esco: <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/model#>      
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>   
SELECT ?position    
WHERE {     
    ?s rdf:type esco:Occupation. 
    { ?position skos:prefLabel ?label. } 
    UNION 
    { ?position skos:altLabel ?label. } 
    FILTER (lcase(?label)= \"assistante scolaire\"@fr ) 
}
LIMIT 10
```

May it be a problem in the code I'm running? There it is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Make a TDB-backed dataset
    String directory = "data/testtdb" ;
    Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(directory) ;

    // transaction (protects a TDB dataset against data corruption, unexpected process termination and system crashes)
    dataset.begin( ReadWrite.WRITE );
    // assume we want the default model, or we could get a named model here
    Model model = dataset.getDefaultModel();

    try {

          // read the input file - only needs to be done once
          String source = "data/esco.rdf";
          FileManager.get().readModel(model, source, "RDF/XML-ABBREV");

          // run a query

          String queryString =
                    "PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> " +
                    "PREFIX esco: <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/model#> " +     
                    "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> " +  
                    "SELECT ?position " +   
                    "WHERE { "  +   
                    "   ?s rdf:type esco:Occupation. " +
                    "   { ?position skos:prefLabel ?label. } " +
                    "   UNION " +
                    "   { ?position skos:altLabel ?label. }" +
                    "   FILTER (lcase(?label)= \"acuponcteur\"@fr ) " +
                    "}" +
                    "LIMIT 1 "  ;

          Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString) ;

          // execute the query
          QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model) ;
          try {
              ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect() ;
              // taken from apache Jena tutorial 
              ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query) ;

          } finally { 
              qexec.close() ; 
          }

      } finally {
          model.close() ;
          dataset.end();
      }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a first point that may or may not make much difference, you can use a property path to simplify

```
{ ?position skos:prefLabel ?label. } 
UNION 
{ ?position skos:altLabel ?label. }
```

as

```
?position skos:prefLabel|skos:altLabel ?label
```

This makes the query:

```
SELECT ?position    
WHERE {     
    ?s rdf:type esco:Occupation.                   # (1)
    ?position skos:prefLabel|skos:altLabel ?label  # (2)
    FILTER (lcase(?label)="acuponcteur"@fr ) 
}
```

What's the point of ?s in this query?  There are some number *n* of ?position/?label pairs that match (2), and some number *m* values of ?s that match (1).  The number of results that you get from the query is *m×n*, but you never use the value of ?s.  It looks like you used DISTINCT to get rid of some repeated values, but you didn't look to see *why* you were getting repeated values in the first place.  You should simply remove the useless line (1), and have the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?position    
WHERE {     
    ?position skos:prefLabel|skos:altLabel ?label
    FILTER (lcase(?label)="acuponcteur"@fr ) 
}
```

I wouldn't be surprised if, at the point, you don't even need the DISTINCT anymore.

Comment: I'm so ashamed my problem was actually this ?s error... ?s should be ?position as I wanted to select only ?position uri that are of rdf:type esco:Occupation. 
Thanks for the simplification for UNION!
And as for the dataset reading and model creation, I actually put it in another class so that it doesn't have to go through this every time, but i simplified the code for the question.