# Japanese Virtuoso SPARQL EndPoint times out very quickly

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I am trying to use the following query on [Japanese dbpedia SPARQL Endpoint](http://ja.dbpedia.org/sparql)

```
select ?s  (group_concat(?album_ja ; separator = "|") AS ?name_album_ja_csv)  where{
   values ?sType { dbpedia-owl:Song
                       dbpedia-owl:Single
    } .
      ?s a ?sType .
      ?s (dbpedia-owl:album|^dbpedia-owl:album)* ?albums;rdfs:label ?album_ja      
    }group by ?s order by ?s offset 0 limit 10
```

but I get this error **Virtuoso 42000 Error The estimated execution time 1005 (sec) exceeds the limit of 400 (sec).**  Almost any query involving group by has this problem. Is this a server problem? Is my query inefficient? How can I get around it?

Comment: Two things seem likely.  1) You're not *using* ?o or ?oType anywhere, so they simply multiply the number of results you've got greatly.  (see [sparql query running forever](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25304721/1281433)) 2)  The property path `(dbpedia-owl:album|^dbpedia-owl:album)*` is probably estimated to be pretty complex. Do you really need to follow arbitrary length paths in both directions?  Would `?` work rather than `*`?  Or `{0,1}` (which isn't part of standard SPARQL, but I think Virtuoso accepts it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but since `?o` isn't used in the results, you can get rid of it.  Even after you do that, though, you'll still have the same problem.  You need to change the property path somehow.  I don't think that you actually need arbitrary length paths in both directions.  You could use `?` instead of `*` to say "path of length 0 or 1" and thus:

```
select ?s
       (group_concat(?album_ja ; separator = "|") AS ?name_album_ja_csv)
where {
  values ?sType { dbpedia-owl:Song dbpedia-owl:Single }
  ?s a ?sType .
  ?s (dbpedia-owl:album|^dbpedia-owl:album)? ?album_ja      
}
group by ?s
limit 100
```

[SPARQL results](http://ja.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fja.dbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fs%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28group_concat%28%3Falbum_ja%20%3B%20separator%20%3D%20%22%7C%22%29%20AS%20%3Fname_album_ja_csv%29%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3FsType%20%7B%20dbpedia-owl%3ASong%20dbpedia-owl%3ASingle%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3Fs%20a%20%3FsType%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fs%20%28dbpedia-owl%3Aalbum%7C%5Edbpedia-owl%3Aalbum%29%3F%20%3Falbum_ja%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Agroup%20by%20%3Fs%0D%0Alimit%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

Note that a path of length 0 is going to be a link to itself, so one value of `?album_ja` is always going to be the same as `?s`.  Is this really what you want?

Comment: As you mentioned, The problem was (dbpedia-owl:album|^dbpedia-owl:album)* when I replaced it with (dbpedia-owl:album|^dbpedia-owl:album){1}

Comment: There's no reason to use `{1}`;  that just says "exactly one time", which is the same as `dbpedia-owl:album|^dbpedia-owl:album`.

Comment: The problem is now the offset. for offset 9990 limit 10, it return data but when I do offset 10000, it returns nothing. The Japanese dbpedia has the limit of 10000, I know but isn't hat offset is supposed to do here?

Comment: offset and limit only make sense if you're ordering the results.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25147648/1281433) to [How to resolve the execution limits in Linkedmdb](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25141247/1281433).

Comment: That is what I thought but without {1} at the end of (dbpedia-owl:album|^dbpedia-owl:album), I will get this error SPARQL compiler: Internal error: sparp_tree_full_clone_int(): unsupported type of expression

Comment: Regarding the offset comment, yes I did follow your instruction and did use "order by". Look at my original query. It has group by ?s order by ?s offset 0 limit 10, I just changed the offset to be 10000

Comment: Hm, I see what you mean about Virtuoso accepting `xxx{1}`, but not `xxx`.  Just a strange bit of Virtuoso, I guess.  I see that you've updated your question, but [your **original query**](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25451330/1) did not have `order by`.

Comment: Yes I did, so what should I do for the offset thing? the offset 9990 limit 10 works fine but offset 10000 limit 10 return nothing. is it a bug?

Comment: If you  use something like `limit 10 offset 10000` you get the message `Virtuoso 22023 Error SR353: Sorted TOP clause specifies more then 10010 rows to sort. Only 10000 are allowed. Either decrease the offset and/or row count or use a scrollable cursor`.  I think you'll need to do one of those things.  At this point, though, that's really a different question. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20939857/1281433) and its comments.

Comment: Sometimes I get the error you showed but this time I just got no values. Strange.  Thanks a lot for always being helpful